# Error running a Rails app in RVM: 'Could not open library'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, imagemagick, rvm

Under 10.4.11, ruby-1.9.2-p290 and RVM I've just installed gems from an app's gemfile, but on running the server I get the following (a search only yields two similar questions, both unanswered), so even hints are welcome:

```
$ rails server
/Users/deveritt/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/ffi-1.0.9/lib/ffi/library.rb:75:in `block in ffi_lib': Could not open library 'libmagic.1.dylib': dlopen(libmagic.1.dylib, 5): image not found. Could not open library 'libmagic.so.1': dlopen(libmagic.so.1, 5): image not found. Could not open library 'libmagic.so.1.dylib': dlopen(libmagic.so.1.dylib, 5): image not found. Could not open library 'magic1.dll': dlopen(magic1.dll, 5): image not found. Could not open library 'libmagic1.dll.dylib': dlopen(libmagic1.dll.dylib, 5): image not found (LoadError)
        from /Users/deveritt/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/ffi-1.0.9/lib/ffi/library.rb:54:in `map'
        from /Users/deveritt/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/ffi-[SNIP]
```

3.0.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:27:in `<top (required)>'
            from script/rails:6:in`require'
            from script/rails:6:in `'

Is this familiar to anyone?

Update: found a Homebrew [install just for libmagic](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/libmagic.rb) that avoids the horrendous ImageMagick install, adapted it for a straight install without brew (YMMV):

get the file:

```
curl -O 'ftp://ftp.astron.com/pub/file/file-5.04.tar.gz'
```

Unzip etc. (or double-click) and move the resulting folder to /tmp, then `./configure`, `make` and `sudo make install` as usual (see the file INSTALL if not sure). After this, RoR launched.

Comment: Do you have libmagic installed?

Comment: Thought I had, haven't. ImageMagick is what's needed, then the Ruby gem, and ImageMagick is no picnic on OS X without MacPorts, which I don't want...

Comment: remove macports; install homebrew.

Comment: Fixed, after digging around - see update. No MacPorts, No brew (not that I have anything against them)...